# Problems with Heroku App and mobile phone

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku

i've made this App and deploy on Heroku:
https://razeftv.herokuapp.com/

there the project with code if you need
https://github.com/AlexGioffre/Razeft

but if i try to open on mobile get only the background and nothing more why?

on pc everything work

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We're not going to go off-site and dig through your code or look at your site ourselves to figure out what's happening. Your question should be self-contained, including everything we need to know directly in it.

Answer (score -1):

this line

```
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

was the problem, i resolve everything